# Как отключить перелистывание в ViewPager,когда проводишь пальцем вбок,если хочешь,чтобы страницы перелистывались по нажатию на специальную кнопку?

Tags: java, android

Делаю реализацию PagerAdapter через FragmentPagerAdapter.Для этого создал сам фрагмент и указал кол-во страниц.Однако есть проблема:хочу,чтобы переход между страницами был не с помощью свапа в сторону,а с помощью нажатия на специальную кнопку.Буду благодарен за любую помощь.Cнизу мой код.При переходе на следующую страницу показывает ее номер.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
private int pageNumber;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", page);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public PageFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    TextView pageHeader=(TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.displayText);
    String header = String.format("Фрагмент %d", pageNumber+1);
    pageHeader.setText(header);
    return result;
}
```

}

/**отдельный класс**

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return(12);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return(PageFragment.newInstance(position));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Я в свое время не нашел выхода, кроме как использовать кастомный ViewPager:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean scrollState;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.scrollState = true;
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.scrollState && super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.scrollState && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.scrollState = enabled;
}
}
```

В методе onCreate отключаем скролл:

```
customViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

Не забываем и в разметке сменить ViewPager:

```
<com.example.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант проще, наследуете ViewPager, и в двух ниже показанных методах возвращаете false.

```
 public class NonSweepViewPager extends ViewPager {


public NonSweepViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}

}
```

Навигацию осуществляем TabLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<com.example.NonSweepViewPager
    android:id="@+id/non_sweep_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

в активити находим tabLayout и nonSweepViewPager

```
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    nonSweepViewPager = findViewById(R.id.non_sweep_viewpager)
```

связываем их

```
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(nonSweepViewPager);
```

Ну и иконки для вкладок. Каждая должна соответствовать заданному фрагменту.

```
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_1);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_2);
```

Теперь нажимаешь на вкладки и переходишь к нужному фрагменту.

Comment: А как связать данный класс с Main?

Comment: McDagen написал как. В разметке помещаем свой элемент как стандартный View, в активти получаем его по id и используем.

Comment: Сейчас отключил перелистывание во фрагментах.Не знаете,как теперь реализовать переход между ними по нажатию на кнопку?Буду благодарен.

Comment: Для навигации нужен TabLayout, сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: Думаю TabLayout мне не подойдет.Такая ситуация,что у меня приложение-обучалка, содержащее тестовые задания с вариантами ответов.Так вот идеей было,что когда пользователь выберет какой-либо ответ,то по нажатию на кнопку он переходит в следующий фрагмент,содержащий уже другое задание.Однако,как все это реализовать,пока что не совсем понимаю

Comment: Зачем тогда ViewPager?

Comment: Есть ли какая-нибудь идея получше?)

Comment: Тот же FrameLayout, по нажатию на кнопку выводишь в нем нужный 
 фрагмент.